# How to: Swap options with jQuery using Address

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to swap to option values between them.
I made a simple fiddle which would swap inputs but when I change it to select options it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using the method of Address. Eg:

```
var prevAddress = $(this).parent().prev('.forms').find('.first option');
    var nextAddress = $(this).parent().next('.forms').find('.second option');
    var tmp = prevAddress.val();
    prevAddress.val(nextAddress.val());
    nextAddress.val(tmp);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfe8K/

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<select>` elements don't work that way. The `.val()` of a `<select>` element is the current value but you can't set a `<select>` to a value that it doesn't contain, you have to make sure that the `<select>` has an `<option>` child that matches the value you want to set; just calling `.val('pancakes')` doesn't add an `<option value="pancakes">` to the `<select>`.

What you need to do is move the contained `<option>` element from the first `<select>` to the second and vice versa. Something more like this:

```
$('.swap a').click(function() {
    var opt1 = $(this).parent().prev('.forms').find('option');
    var opt2 = $(this).parent().next('.forms').find('option');

    $(this).parent().prev('.forms').find('select').append(opt2);
    $(this).parent().next('.forms').find('select').append(opt1);
});
```

And an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/VrUmQ/1/

Comment: Thanks. It works but it doesn't seem to be working with jquery-ui if applied on the select boxes.

Comment: @jQueryBeast: You didn't say anything about jQuery-UI. You may have to destroy and rebind the selectmenus to get them to reread the underlying `<select>` elements.

Comment: And I thought jQuery's motto was "do more, write less". That is vastly more code that is required for a POJS solution, there should also be much more efficient jQuery solutions too. There is no need to remove then re-add the options, you can just assign one of them to its new location.

Comment: @RobG: Sure, the `detach` isn't necessary (so I yanked it out). And yes, the chains are a lot longer than I'd use but I left those alone because maybe there are reasons for them.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have a reference to a select element and you want to swap the first two options, then:

```
  select.insertBefore(select.options[1], select.options[0]);
```

will do the trick.